# Modifying a fibonacci program with an exception

Tags: java, exception, fibonacci

I have being given a task to see what will happen when I input a non integer value like a,b,c etc to this program called FibonacciNumber. I need to use an exception and modify the program so that it does not terminate abruptly and instead gives the user a meaningful message. being stuck on this task for a day and a half now and still having trouble how to do this.

```
public class FibonacciNumber {
    public static long fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try {
        if (N < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers are not allowed");
        }
        System.out.println(N);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surround the `parseInt` call with a try-catch block, since that is the method that will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not a number. Or just move the `try {` one line up.

Comment: not sure if I am implementing it right, could you please show me how its coded, I am still pletty newbie at these kind of things

Comment: `int N; try { N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); } catch (exception e) { System.out.println("Not a valid number: " + args[0]); return; }`

Comment: so do i replace that with the try and catch i already have?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i shall put these in my note book for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is check the NumberFormatException that is thrown when parsing the input. This is done like so:

```
int n;
try {
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Your error message ");
     return; // make sure the program cannot continue to execute
}
```

Comment: i tried it out but seems to get an error, i probably didn't implement correctly, could you please show me the whole program when this is modified into it. i am still pretty newb at this sorry, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: @LearningToProgram Whats the error? I'm on mobile right now so I can't post all the code sorry

Comment: @LearningToProgram yep no problem just press the check mark on the answer to mark it solved